# Extjs 5 add filters to grid dynamically on reconfigure

Tags: extjs5

I have a grid that is generated dynamically

I build the columns array and store, then call reconfigure on my grid

Next I create a filter array. Now filters have to be applied to the columns in my grid.

But the filters are not reflected in my grid. How can ths be achieved?

myView.js

```
Ext.define('myView.view.myView', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   plugins: 'gridfilters',
   store: 'myStore.store.myStore',
   pageSize:10, 
   dockedItems: [{
      xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
      store: 'WhiskerPlot.store.settingStore',   // same store GridPanel is using
      dock: 'bottom',
      displayInfo: true
  }],
   filters :[]
});
```

myController.js

```
var colFilters = [];
colFilters.push({
                    type : 'list',
                    dataIndex : dummyDataIndex,
                    options : [small,large]
                });      

var filters = {
                    ftype : 'filters',
                    filters : colFilters
            };
var gridview = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('myView')[0];
gridview.reconfigure(store,columnarr);
gridview.filters.addFilters(filters);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the filters to the column array itself.

Copied from: [Filters Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.filters.Filters)

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
     store: {
         url: 'path/to/data'
     },

     plugins: 'gridfilters',

     columns: [{
         dataIndex: 'id',
         text: 'Id',

         filter: 'number'
     }, {
         dataIndex: 'name'
         text: 'Name',

         filter: {
             type: 'string',
             value: 'Ben'
         }
     }, {
         ...
     }]
});
```